# Insert and update using proc sql simultaneously in SAS

Tags: sas

I am importing a file using proc import

```
proc import datafile="/opt/Export_d.csv" replace
out=work.export_data; run;
```

THEN I SELECTED 2 VARIABLES FROM EXPORTED TABLE HAVING SOME CONDITION
proc SQL;

```
create table work.login2
as select ' SURVEY_ID'n, TIME format=datetime20.,' USERNAME'n
from work.export_data
having TIME=max(TIME) and ' USERNAME'="sasdemo";
quit;
```

then i created a macro for survey_id because i have to update a value with the Survey_id reference in different table shown in below code:

```
proc SQL;
select max(' SURVEY_ID'n) into: sid from work.login2;
quit;
```

now if the ID is blank then i don't have to insert anything but if we have survey_id we have update few columns in a table using below code which is not happening.

```
proc SQL;
case when ' SURVEY_ID'n is not null then update table_name set SAS_TRACKING_CODE="&Trackingcode."
where SURVEY_ID=&sid.
else end;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your proc sql is not valid. At all. `case when`can only be used within statemements like `select`, `where`, `order by`.
The following will do your update if SURVEY_ID is not blank:

```
proc sql;
  update table_name
  set SAS_TRACKING_CODE="&Trackingcode"
  where SURVEY_ID=&sid. and SURVEY_ID is not null
  ;
quit;
```

If what you want is to execute the `update` **only** when a condition is true, you should use a macro.

**EDIT:** that macro would look like this:

```
%macro update;
  %if %symexist(sid) and not &sid = %then %do;
   proc sql;
      update table_name
      set SAS_TRACKING_CODE="&Trackingcode"
      where SURVEY_ID=&sid.
      ;
    quit;
  %end;
%mend;
```

Comment: Sorry I have written the wrong code. I have written the below code:
proc sql;
update table_name
set SAS_TRACKING_CODE = "&Trackingcode."
where SURVEY_ID=&sid. and SURVEY_ID is not null;
quit;

But Now i Want one more condition where it says Survey_ID is Null then do nthg.

Comment: @AkshayPatil I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The above query _will_ do nothing if survey_id is null.